# ng-repeat track by $index display the item only once if the similar key exists multiple times in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was getting  [ngRepeat:dupes]: error in my angularjs code.
So I searched on stackoverflow and found the solution which stated to use track by $index. This is working for me now. But, it displays the item multiple times if the same key is present multiple times. I want to display only one item if the same key exists multiple times.
here is my sample code from the view :

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:myFilter track by $index">
</div>
```

here is the current output :
 [image]

Insted of showing these two cards, I want the code to show only one card as they both are the same.
How do I do it?

Comment: You missed " and 
Use user in users track by $index | filter:myFilter
I may helps you.

Comment: I edited the question and user in users track by $index | filter:myFilter doesn't work

Comment: Why don't you remove duplicates before passing the list to the ng-repeat?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222555/angularjs-remove-duplicate-elements-in-ng-repeat

Comment: Please show your users array, once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass array into a function and create an array without the repeating values
like **myFunction(users)** so the repeat section will become **ng-repeat="user in myFunction(users)"**. Write the function yourself.

Comment: please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591159/optimise-ng-bind-directive-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this by creating a filter:

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.filter('unique', function() {
   // we will return a function which will take in a collection
   // and a keyname
   return function(collection, keyname) {
      // we define our output and keys array;
      var output = [],
          keys = [];

      // we utilize angular's foreach function
      // this takes in our original collection and an iterator function
      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
          // we check to see whether our object exists
          var key = item[keyname];
          // if it's not already part of our keys array
          if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              // add it to our keys array
              keys.push(key);
              // push this item to our final output array
              output.push(item);
          }
      });
      // return our array which should be devoid of
      // any duplicates
      return output;
   };
});

app.controller('listdata', function($scope, $http) {

your controller logic for the users array
   });

});
```

In the view :

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users |unique:'name' | filter:myFilter track by $index">
</div>
```

Comment: its better to use function than filter because filter will get called multiple times but function does not. See my answer.